# What are the `y` and `x` params to the python curses `window.getch()` method?

Tags: python, coordinates, curses, coordinate-systems, python-curses

I may be missing something very obvious, but
I am confused by the optional `[y, x]` parameters to the `window.getch( [y, x] )` method [described in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch).  What are these optional params for, and what do they do if I include them in my call?

As far as I can tell the documentation doesn't mention what these parameters are for.  It just says:

> Get a character. Note that the integer returned does not have to be in ASCII range: function keys, keypad keys and so on are represented by numbers higher than 255. In no-delay mode, return -1 if there is no input, otherwise wait until a key is pressed.

The `window.get_wch( [y, x] )` and `window.getkey( [y, x] )` methods seem to have similarly undescribed optional `[y, x]` params.

Comment: isn't it just the coordinates? So get character at coordinates y,x?

Comment: no, it is definitely not the coordinates to _read_ from.  `getch()` `get_wch()` and `getkey()` all read from the _keyboard_ not the screen.  You may be thinking of the `window.inch(y, x)` method?  That has required y, x params, and gets the character at window location y, x. https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.inch

Comment: The `y, x` are [documented in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#displaying-text), which is referenced at the top of the curses-binding documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to go to the old curses library man pages to find an answer.  The extra arguments move the cursor to the specified position.  The  thing I didn't realize is that these methods are not always just reading keyboard input.  *They can also modify the screen state*, which is not at all obvious from the documentation.  In the (not typically used) `echo` mode, these curses functions echo the keyboard input back to the screen.

[Older versions of the curses man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) for example, say:

> Unless noecho has been set, then the character will also be echoed into the designated window according to the following rules: If the character is the current erase character, left arrow, or backspace, the cursor is moved one space to the left and that screen position is erased as if delch had been called. If the character value is any other KEY_ define, the user is alerted with a beep call. Otherwise the character is simply output to the screen.

And then the netbsd man page for https://man.netbsd.org/curses_input.3 further describes the behavior of the `mvgetch()` function as:

> The mvgetch() and mvwgetch() functions are the same as the getch() and wgetch() functions, respectively, excepting that wmove() is called to move the cursor to the position specified by y, x before the character is read.

So, if noecho is unset, then the Python `getch()` method with no params calls the C `getch()` function, and the key read from the keyboard is echoed at the current screen location.  If the Python `getch( y, x )` method is called with the optional y and x params, then the C `mvgetch( y, x)` function is invoked, which moves the cursor to `y, x`, and then does `getch()`.

Here is the code for `_curses_window_getch_impl()` in the curses Module of the cpython interpreter where we can see that that wgetch() or mvwgetch() are getting called depending on whether the optional params are provided: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_cursesmodule.c#L1401

Comment: As mentioned in another q/a, that "die" site documents a rather old(er) version of [ncurses](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) version 5.7 (patch 20090207).

Comment: The quote from NetBSD's manual page dates from October 2002.  ncurses is updated more frequently (and recently) than that.  [Current](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) version is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#windows-and-pads

> Note that the coordinate system used in curses is unusual. Coordinates are always passed in the order y,x, and the top-left corner of a window is coordinate (0,0). This breaks the normal convention for handling coordinates where the x coordinate comes first. This is an unfortunate difference from most other computer applications, but it’s been part of curses since it was first written, and it’s too late to change things now.
>
> Your application can determine the size of the screen by using the curses.LINES and curses.COLS variables to obtain the y and x sizes. Legal coordinates will then extend from (0,0) to (curses.LINES - 1, curses.COLS - 1).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

> Note: Whenever x or y arguments to a function or a method are optional, they default to the current cursor location. Whenever attr is optional, it defaults to A_NORMAL.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.getsyx

> Return the current coordinates of the virtual screen cursor as a tuple (y, x). If leaveok is currently True, then return (-1, -1).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.addch

> Paint character ch at (y, x) with attributes attr, overwriting any character previously painted at that location. By default, the character position and attributes are the current settings for the window object.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#displaying-text

> Move to position y,x within the window

> Windows remember where the cursor was left after the last operation, so if you leave out the y,x coordinates, the string or character will be displayed wherever the last operation left off. You can also move the cursor with the move(y,x) method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.  I get that when we're refering to screen coordinates in curses we refer to y, x, not x, y.  I get that when screen coordinates are optional, then we default to the "current" coordinates.  But my question is about `getch()`, `get_wch()` and `getkey()` which all read from the keyboard, and don't impact the screen state at all (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

Python's curses binding is based on the underlying curses API, without (for example) generalizing windows and pads into an true object-programming model.  The `y,x` come from the curses API, which uses different function names for the versions with/without these parameters.  Referring to the ncurses [getch](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) manpage:

> `int getch(void);`
> `int wgetch(WINDOW *`*`win`*`)`;
>
> `int mvgetch(int` *y*`, int` *x*`);`
> `int mvwgetch(WINDOW *`*win*`, int` *y*`, int` *x*`);`

The main [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Routine-and-Argument-Names) manpage explains the parameters:

> The  routines  prefixed with ***mv*** require a *y* and *x* coordinate to move to
> before performing the appropriate action.  The ***mv*** routines imply a call
> to  move before the call to the other routine.  The coordinate *y* always
> refers to the row (of the window), and *x* always refers to  the  column.
> The upper left-hand corner is always (0,0), not (1,1).

Like the ncurses manpages, the Python curses documentation has a "main" part, which is the tutorial [*Curses Programming with Python*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#curses-howto).  That [outlines](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#displaying-text) the way these optional parameters are used (**overloading** the names):

> From a C programmer’s point of view, curses may sometimes look like a twisty maze of functions, all subtly different. For example, `addstr`() displays a string at the current cursor location in the stdscr window, while `mvaddstr`() moves to a given ***y,x*** coordinate first before displaying the string. `waddstr`() is just like `addstr`(), but allows specifying a window to use instead of using *`stdscr`* by default. `mvwaddstr`() allows specifying both a window and a coordinate.
>
>
> Fortunately the Python interface hides all these details. *`stdscr`* is a window object like any other, and methods such as `addstr`() accept multiple argument forms. Usually there are four different forms.

Unlike most *graphical* systems (which use the horizontal ordinate **x** first), curses uses the vertical ordinate **y** first.  That probably came about from dealing with hardware terminals (more than 90% of the entries in the terminal database use row,column order for cursor-addressing).  However, the low-level terminfo and termcap function [`tgoto`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html#h3-Formatting-Capabilities) is inconsistent with the high-level curses functions:

> Doing this shows a quirk in **`tgoto`**: *most hardware terminals use cursor addressing with row first, but the original developers  of  the
> termcap  interface  chose  to  put the column parameter first.*  The
> **`tgoto`** function swaps the order of parameters.  It  does  this  also
> for  calls  requiring  only  a single parameter.  In that case, the
> first parameter is merely a placeholder.